# get RadioGroup count in android

Tags: android, radio-button

I am creating a number of ( dynamic ) radiogroup in a linear layout. Each having 4 radio buttons in it. There are Some `TextViews` inside that linearLayout.

My question is On a button press, I need to get all the radioGroup for fetching data.

I tried the following, but getting the whole count including textViews

```
LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.questions_lay);
int childcount = ll.getChildCount();
```

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
public void getViewType(ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < viewGroup.getChildCount(); index++)
    {
        View childView = viewGroup.getChildAt(index);

        if (childView instanceof RadioGroup)
        {
            System.err.println("RadioGroup " + index);
            getViewType((ViewGroup) childView);
        }
        else if (childView instanceof RadioButton)
        {
            System.err.println("RadioButton " + index);
        }
        else if (childView instanceof TextView)
        {
            System.err.println("TextView " + index);
        }
    }
}
```

When you get the `instanceOf` `RadioGroup` you call `getViewType` again if you want to access the `RadioButton` within that `RadioGroup`

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/), how they are fetching data through "radio_button".

For example to fetch data using radio button use this:

```
RadioButton rBtnUp = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.xml_file_forUPID);
RadioButton rBtnDown = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.XML_file_forDOWNID);
TextView txtCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCountId);
      txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count)); // Display initial count

     Button btnCount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCountId);
      // Process the button on-click event
      btnCount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            if (rBtnUp.isChecked()) { // Counting up
               count++;
            } else if (rBtnDown.isChecked()) { // Counting down
               count--;
            }
            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is for TextView. You can use this for any type of view.

```
//Recursively search for TextView in given ViewGroup
public int getTextViewCount(ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View childView = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);

        if (childView instanceof TextView) {
            count++;
        }
        if (childView instanceof ViewGroup) {
            count += getTextViewCount((ViewGroup) childView);
        }

    }
    return count;

}
```